# oracle WHERE condition from prev month

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, min

I am working on a requirement where in, my Oracle query should ignore those prescriptions that started last month and spanned over to this month.

```
Prescription# Date_In     Date_Out     STATUS

123456        02-JAN-2018 03-JAN-2018  Pre-Verification   
123456        02-JAN-2018 03-JAN-2018  Verification  
234567        31-DEC-2017 02-JAN-2018  Pre-Verification  
234567        31-DEC-2017 02-JAN-2018  Pre-Verification  
234567        31-DEC-2017 02-JAN-2018  Verification  
345678        01-JAN-2018 02-JAN-2018  Pre-Verification  
345678        01-JAN-2018 02-JAN-2018  Verification
```

Desired result:

```
Prescription# Date_In     Date_Out     Status

123456        02-JAN-2018 03-JAN-2018  Pre-Verification  
123456        02-JAN-2018 03-JAN-2018  Verification  
345678        01-JAN-2018 02-JAN-2018  Pre-Verification  
345678        01-JAN-2018 02-JAN-2018  Verification
```

My SQL (which brings back all three rows but ideally it should bring back only
2 rows)

```
SELECT PRESCRIPTION#,DATE_IN,DATE_OUT  
FROM PRESCRIPTION_TABLE  
WHERE DATE_IN >= '01-JAN-2018'  
AND DATE_OUT <= '31-JAN-2018';
```

I also tried, but this also brought back all the 3 prescriptions.

```
SELECT PRESCRIPTION#,DATE_IN,DATE_OUT  
FROM PRESCRIPTION_TABLE  
GROUP BY PRESCRIPTION#,DATE_OUT    
HAVING MIN(DATE_IN) > '01-JAN-2018';
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Clear as mud. You posted this on 20 February 2018; so what is "last month" and "this month"? Your sample data has dates in December 2017 and January 2018. Then - what do you mean by "started" and "spanned over"? The earliest DATE_IN and the most recent DATE_OUT for each prescription, regardless of STATUS? If not, what else? And, do you just need the prescription number, or all the other information for the selected ones? The GROUP BY query will lose information (even after it is corrected), is that OK or do you really need the output you said you need?

Comment: So your desired result has 4 rows, you say you get *all* 3 rows, but really want 2 rows? .... Confused....

Comment: `Where format(date_in,'YYYYMM') = format(date_out,'YYYYMM')`?  If I understand you just want only those records where the datein/dateout have the same month/year  Though this wouldn't be that "fast"  I"m sure there's better ways to handle this...

Answer (score 0):

Truncating a date with the `MM` mask gives the first of that month. Passing `-1` as the second argument to `add_months()` gives us last month. `last_day()` provides the last day of the month.  Using these three functions will give you all the prescriptions which started and finished in last month:

```
select distinct prescription#,date_in,date_out  
from prescription_table  
where date_in >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'), -1)   
and date_out <= last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'), -1)) ;
```

The `distinct` is necessary because you have a poorly-normalized data model: the prescription status should be in a separate table.